# JavaScript function loops twice as many times every time ran

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops

I'm trying to use a function in JavaScript (+JQuery) which is like a sound calibrator system.  It starts at one frequency band, plays it, asks the user if they can hear it - then if the can it knows the lowest frequency of their system and if not it goes up to the next band and then re-checks etc. until the lowest frequency is found.

However, when I run the function, it seems to run itself twice as many times each time.  From the testFreqNum alert I could see the first time it added 1 once, the second time it added 1 then added it again, third time it did it 4 times, then 8 etc.

Probably an easy error to fix - I'm new to JavaScript so maybe you can see it straight away? Thanks.

```
function testFreq(band, testType){

if (testType == 'testLow') {
    $('#calibrationText').html('<h5>Testing ' + freqs[band] + 'Hz...</h>');
    playSound('Tones', band);
    //window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('#calibrationText').html('<h5>Could you hear ' + freqs[band] + 'Hz clearly?</h>');
    $('#yes').fadeIn(500).click(function(){

        bandMin = band;//sets randGen's min availible band value
        testFreqNum = 31;//sets test frequency to upper high
        testFreq(testFreqNum, 'testHigh');//runs calibrator again in high mode starting band 31
        $('#yes').fadeOut(500);
        $('#no').fadeOut(500);
    });

    $('#no').fadeIn(500).click(function(){

        testFreqNum = testFreqNum + 1;
        alert(testFreqNum);
        testFreq(testFreqNum, 'testLow');//runs calibrator again in low mode
        //$('#yes').fadeOut(500);
        //$('#no').fadeOut(500);
    });
    // }, 4000);
}
```

...and the rest...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're binding an *additional* click handler each time, if you want to change it, just [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) first, like this:

```
 $('#yes').fadeIn(500).unbind("click").click(function(){
```

...and the same for `#no`, otherwise each time you call [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) you're attaching a new `click` event handler, but not removing the previous one, so both get executed...and an additional one added each time.